How to resolve difference in font rendering between Chrome on Windows & Chromium on CentOS via chrome-php?
I am using chrome-php to render webpages in headless mode on my CentOS server. The webpages load a HTML 5 canvas via fabric.js. The text renders as intended on Chrome in Windows but on CentOS via chrome-php, the text is enlarged as seen in the image below:

The text font in both the screenshots is same Opificio. The Opificio font is being loaded on the page using the following css:
<style> @font-face {font-family:"Opificio"; src:url("https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/fpd_fonts/Opificio.ttf") format("TrueType");} </style>
However, the text size/style is different. The issue seems to be happening with certain fonts only. I tried the same text with another font and there was no variation in rendering. How to resolve this?

Doesn't appear to be a mere size issue - look at the digits, those look completely different. Looks like it is either using a different font variant, or not rendering these digits in your desired target font at all to begin with.

Possibly one of the systems doesn't have the same fonts installed as the other - have you checked? That's asuming you're not serving the font files in with the website itself, of course? We don't really know if that's the case or not though, because we weren't supplied with a [mre] of the issue, as per [ask]. We can't fix pictures. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

I have added the required info in the original question.

That single line of code you've shared does not generate the given image at all

While that update is useful and should definitely be part of what you provide, it's self-evidently not a [mre] of the issue all by itself. Try to make sure your updates actually give all the information which was requested, not just one small bit of it

A quick look at two different sites shows that the font "Opificio" does not contain glyphs for numbers

The font file I am using has glyphs for numbers. I have uploaded the font file here - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/bce728df87322c8de2d768687f62fc7220241014140300/25fdd5

I just opened the provided font in FontForge, as well as FontDrop, and they show that those glyphs are missing. How are you verifying that they exist?

It looks like the two lines on the T-shirt are rendered in two different ways. This is why we need a minimal reproducible example. My guess is that the two "browsers" just use a different fall-back font because something's wrong with the font. I cannot confirm that this font cannot render numbers, it seems like it can.

As explained by Chris Haas your font doesn't include glyphs for digits so the browser will take a fallback (e.g Times on windows/MacOS some sans-serif on centOS). You could specify a font by adding a custom @font-face rule for the number unicode range U+30-39:  See "Font-variant-numeric for Google Fonts"

As pointed out by Chris Haas & others, the issue was resolved by loading fonts on the website and not relying on system fonts as they are different across different Operating Systems.
For fonts without numeric glyphs like Opificio, the issue is resolved by uploading a version of the font with numeric glyphs as in their absence, numbers are rendered in an OS specific way leading to variations in rendering.
